# Should CSS selectors include elements from the DOM?

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I studied front end dev at the university a few years ago, our teacher taught us to always provide the full (almost) parental
DOM hierarchy of the targeted element within our CSS selectors.

So in our web projects we had to write selectors like:

```css
div#container div#content p.bread a.external { }
```

instead of just:

```css
#container #content .bread .external { }
```

or (I see the disadvantages with class conflicts that may occur here)

```css
.external { }
```

I personally write my selectors like

```css
#container #content p.bread a.external {}
```

until I recently read an article saying that it should be avoided (but with no obvious reason why) and another article saying the same but that one was intended for jQuery selectors.

Was my teacher wrong and what is the right (fastest to parse and with most support) way of writing CSS selectors?

Comment: The "fastest to parse" way is not always the "right" way.

Comment: Wise words @BoltClock. What would you say is the "right" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My 2 cents

Specific enough to target only what needs targeting (as others have said) is the general rule.

I agree with lonesomeday that "difference in performance will be minimal," but every added element in the chain is one more check to be done.

**So Think About How to Reduce It**

---

*Are the ID's needed?*

I disagree with Spudley that "there should never be a need to specify more than one ID in a selector." If your site is set up to have different display on different pages, and so `#page1 #content` is different than `#page2 #content` for displaying, then that is a *legitimate case* of two id's in one selector. However,

1. If all pages are `#container #content` then the drop the `#container`.
2. Also, if all `p.bread` elements are *inside* `#content`, then drop that selector also.

---

*Are element names needed?*

1. Is `.bread` intended to be used on anything other than a `p`? If not, drop the `p`.
2. Is `.external` intended to be used on anything other than an `a` (probably linking to an external site)? If not, drop the `a`.

---

*Is the decedent relation of classes needed?*

Is the `.bread .external` significant for display? That is, does `.external` exist outside of a `.bread` parent and does it change because of that parent? If so, then keep the relation. Otherwise, if the important thing is only the `.external` (no matter where it is), then that is the only selector you need.

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, you should use the least specific selectors you can.

`div#container div#content p.bread a.external { }` is a very, very specific selector. It is unnecessarily specific. There can only be one `#content` element, and it will surely always be within `#container`.

Write general rules. Don't attempt to target the precise DOM element. If `a.external` will capture the set of elements you want, use that. Otherwise you'll end up having to write `p.bread a.external`, `p.potato a.external`, `p.olive a.external`, etc, etc.

The difference in performance will be minimal. The benefits of general, reusable rules are large.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your teacher was wrong.

From your example:

```
div#container div#content p.bread a.external { }
```

1. Given that an ID in a DOM document **must** be unique, there should never be a need to specify more than one ID in a selector. So the above selector that contains both `#container` and `#content` is immediately wrong simply by that criteria.
2. An ID is the most efficient and direct way to reference an element. Again, it's unique and instantly accessible, so there's no need to qualify it in any way, so adding `div` in front of either of the `#container` or `#content` here is redundant.
3. The other two parts of the selector `p.bread` and `a.external` are likely to be wrong, but it's not so clear-cut for these.

   A selector only needs to specify the parts that are necessary to select the elements required and exclude any elements that are not required. In this example, if all `.bread` elements are `p`s or all `.external` elements are `a`s then the element type `a` or `p` would be redundant and should be dropped. But without seeing your actual HTML content, it's not possible to be certain of this in the way that it is possible for the IDs because a given classname can legitimately be applied to multiple elements of multiple type.

Answer (score 0):

Longer selectors such as `div#container div#content p.bread a.external { }` do take longer, yes. But rarely do they make any noticeable impact on the paint time.

Also, since IDs are (supposed to be) always unique, `div#container` and `div#content` should really just be `#container` and `#content`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways will work, and the impact on speed will *probably* be minimal. However there is no need to add the element to your rule, and I would encourage you not to as it helps your rules become more reusable - something you should always aim for.

You should also avoid using location to target elements. E.g. `.sidebar h3`. Instead, add a class to those `h3`s and target the class. This means you can reuse those styles you wrote elsewhere, just by adding the class. These are all concepts of Object Oriented CSS, and will help you write more efficient CSS by reducing the amount of duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are superfluous (or rather should be) when used with ID selectors (`#`), since your DOM should contain only unique IDs for elements.

It's also worth noting that classes should be used to bunch the styles of the same elements. In case you have two `.bread` elements in your DOM, but want them styled differently, you should consider using a different class name.